# Using an Excel Macro to export only filtered data into a csv file

Tags: excel, vba

I need to export only the filtered data from one table into a new csv file and save as the worksheet name. I have the foundation but I cannot figure out how to save only the filtered data. Here is what I have so far. Any help will be appreciated.

```vb
Sub ExportCSV2()

   Dim wb As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook
   Dim ws As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet

   Set wb = ThisWorkbook
   Set ws = ActiveSheet

   Application.DisplayAlerts = True

   ws.Copy
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=ws.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True
   Windows(ws.Name & ".csv").Activate
   ActiveWorkbook.Close False
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: there is no code even attempting to filter the data out. Use `Auto Filter` method after saving the file and delete the rows you don't need. You could do that before too, but I suspect you want to keep all the data in the original file.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I knew there wasn't anything in the code to filter data out, that's where I'm stuck, what to include to only export the filtered data. I'm not sure how to include the AutoFilter without naming a range which will change each time the macro is run. I'm missing something small I'm sure. And yes I do wish to keep the unfiltered data in the file.

Comment: To clarify, you want to have the user manually filter, then click a button (or otherwise invoke the macro) which will then automatically export the selected data?

Comment: bhbennet3, yes that is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: So if the data is prefiltered and you only want to save out the visible cells, then 1) create new blank workbook, 2) copy visible cells - see Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), 3) paste into new workbook. 4) save new workbook as csv.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this (assuming you re using Windows). It's ugly code but it seems to work.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyToCsv()
    Const FILTERED_COLUMN = 3 'Column on which you apply your filter
    Const TARGET_FOLDER = "C:\temp\" 'Folder you save your CSV files in
    Const FILENAME = "MyFile"
    
    Dim varValue As Variant
    Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim UniqueValues As Object 'scripting.dictionary
    Dim CsvWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim CsvSheet As Worksheet
    
    Set DataSheet = ActiveSheet 'Replace with relevant sheet
    If Not DataSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        DataSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter
    End If
    
    Set UniqueValues = GetUniqueValuesFromColumn(DataSheet, FILTERED_COLUMN)
    For Each varValue In UniqueValues.items()
        DataSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter field:=FILTERED_COLUMN, Criteria1:=varValue
        DataSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        Set CsvWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
        CsvWorkbook.Sheets(1).Paste
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        CsvWorkbook.SaveAs TARGET_FOLDER & FILENAME & "_" & varValue & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, local:=True
        CsvWorkbook.Close
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Next varValue
    
End Sub

Public Function GetUniqueValuesFromColumn(Sht As Worksheet, ColumnNumber As Integer) As Object 'Scripting.dictionary
    Dim Maxrow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Dic As Object 'Scripting.dictionary
    Dim CurrentValue As String
    
    Set Dic = CreateObject("SCRIPTING.DICTIONARY")
    Maxrow = Sht.Cells(1048576, ColumnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To Maxrow
        CurrentValue = Sht.Cells(i, ColumnNumber)
        If Not Dic.exists(CurrentValue) Then
            Dic.Add CurrentValue, CurrentValue
        End If
    Next i
        Set GetUniqueValuesFromColumn = Dic

End Function
```

**Edit :** I think I read the question too fast and overcomplicated the answer... Let's try this instead :

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyToCsv()
    Const FILTERED_COLUMN = 3 'Column on which you apply your filter
    Const TARGET_FOLDER = "C:\temp\" 'Folder you save your CSV files in
    Const MYFILENAME = "MyFile"
    Const FILTERVALUE = 1

    Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim CsvWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim CsvSheet As Worksheet
    
    Set DataSheet = ActiveSheet 'Replace with relevant sheet
    If Not DataSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        DataSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter
    End If
    
    DataSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter field:=FILTERED_COLUMN, Criteria1:=FILTERVALUE
    DataSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Set CsvWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
    CsvWorkbook.Sheets(1).Paste
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    CsvWorkbook.SaveAs FILENAME:=TARGET_FOLDER & MYFILENAME & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, local:=True
    CsvWorkbook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

**Edit 2 :** This should work hopefully...

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyToCsv()
    Const TARGET_FOLDER = "C:\Temp\" 'Folder you save your CSV files in
    Const MYFILENAME = "MyFile"

    Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim CsvWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim CsvSheet As Worksheet
    
    Set DataSheet = ActiveSheet 'Replace with relevant sheet
    DataSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Set CsvWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
    CsvWorkbook.Sheets(1).Paste
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    CsvWorkbook.SaveAs FILENAME:=TARGET_FOLDER & MYFILENAME & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, local:=True
    CsvWorkbook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I realized I had made a mistake (using Datasheet.FilterMode instead of Not DataSheet.AutoFilterMode...). I fixed it in edit.

Comment: I get a Compile error - Variable not defined after replacing ActiveSheet with my sheet name. The name is AcctRateJiras. I think we've very close though as leaving ActiveSheet creates a CSV for all of the sheets in the workbook. 

Very much appreciate the help so far.

Comment: It should be something like set DataSheet = thisworkbook.sheets("AcctRateJiras") .Could you check if it works?

Comment: That creates a separate csv for the filter name and every filter option.

Comment: I realized I misunderstood the question, which was simpler than I thought. I edited my answer. Could you check if it works?

Comment: This corrects the multiple csv files and only exports the active worksheet which is great, but only exports the header row without any data. Also wipes out the filter of the original sheet leaving all filters unchecked.

Comment: Did you change the filter value (FILTERVALUE)? Or do you need to only use current filters?

Comment: Yes, only current active filter should be exported. I did not edit that value.

Comment: Okay i edited my answer accordingly. Could you see if it works?

Comment: Bingo! I really appreciate you working through this. I was missing several pieces of this puzzle and your help was just what I needed. Big thanks.